# How to iterate over class hierarchy?

Tags: kotlin

I want to iterate over class hierarchy and print all super classes:

```
open class A {}
open class B : A() {}
open class C : B() {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var currentClass = C::class
    while(currentClass != Any::class) {
        println(currentClass)
        currentClass = currentClass.superclass
    }
}
```

but Kotlin `KClass` doesn't have `superclass` method.

I have tried to use `superclass` from Java:

```
 currentClass = currentClass.java.superclass.kotlin
```

but it cause compilation error:

```
Error:(9, 52) Type inference failed: 'T' cannot capture 'in ('C'..'C?')'. 
Type parameter has an upper bound 'kotlin.Any' that cannot be satisfied 
capturing 'in' projection
```

So, can anybody explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, specify explicit type for `var currentClass` to avoid its inference as `KClass<C>`:

```
var currentClass: KClass<*> = C::class
```

Then, `superclass` call will return a type [with `in` projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections), and you won't be able to call `.kotlin` on it. So a cast to [star-projected](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) type will also help:

```
currentClass = (currentClass.java.superclass as Class<*>).kotlin
```

Complete method:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var currentClass: KClass<*> = C::class
    while (currentClass != Any::class) {
        println(currentClass)
        currentClass = (currentClass.java.superclass as Class<*>).kotlin
    }
}
```